Is there any program using xAct to Solve Field Equations with Unknowns for a Given Metric?
I am considering solving any field equation with a given metric with unknown variables in it using xAct package in mathematica. Like in many cases, the Schwarzschild like solution holds:
$$ds^2=-B(r)dt^2+B(r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d {\Omega}^2$$
By specifying the Einstein equation, we can obtain the Schwarzschild solution. And I have already tested this using xAct package in mathematica. But when I change the field equation to a more complex one, the result is rather strange and peculiar, like that shown in the picture. I suspect that this program I found on the internet may only valid for solving Einstein equations. I am wondering is there any program using xAct that can solve any filed equations by specifying a metric with unknown variables and by substitute in this metric to the field equation would give the variable and hence solve the metric?
Or, is there any method to simplify the result in the picture?

Please share any code as copy-pastable text, not as an unreadable image.
